# What cases are available?

Tags: case, purchasing

What cases are currently available for the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Related Meta discussion: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-questions-about-peripherals-or-accessories-be-allowed and http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-the-faq-contain

Comment: This relates to appearance, the meta question voted that off-topic.

Comment: Cases are also for safety - http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135/is-it-safe-to-operate-on-any-dry-surface

Comment: Not sure ghis is specific enough.

Comment: Is it possible to close questions for being "too easy to answer via a basic google search"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Adafruit have made an Acrylic snap-together case, available [here](https://www.adafruit.com/products/859).
  [image: Adafruit case]
- There are numerous cases available on eBay, see [this listing](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=120911056407&ssPageName=ADME:L:OC:GB:3160) for an example.
  [image: Ebay case]
- You can also make a case out of lego, see [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1354)
  [image: Lego case]
- You can also print a case out of paper, see [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1310)
  [image: Paper case]
- PI-STACK® ([ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=%20PI-STACK&_sacat=0))([hi-res](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leqDU.jpg))
  [image]
- [Pibow](http://www.pibow.com/)
  [image]

Comment: The second is the one I have :)

Comment: I saw your link on chat! Review?

Comment: It's pretty :) Simple to put together and holds the board firmly so that it doesn't touch the acrylic. A+

Comment: Could heat be an issue with the paper ones? (paper can autoignite)

Answer (score 4):

There is a printable card case available here:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1310

I'm currently using it and whilst it isn't as durable as a plastic one, it does the job.

Comment: Could heat be an issue with a paper case? (paper can autoignite)

Comment: I've been using my pi for some pretty intensive stuff and it doesn't get hot at all - still touchable even when churning away. It is more likely to turn itself off before over heating, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Paper autoignites around 451 F, or 233 C.  I seriously doubt that the raspberry pi is capable of generating that much heat in an unmodified state.

Answer (score 3):

The **PI-STACK** Raspberry Pi case/enclosure is available on Ebay. 
It is very heavily constructed in 10mm clear acrylic with solid metal supports allowing access to cables all round including GPIO and camera sockets.

The PI-STACK even has chrome molybdenum steel internal supports!

["gold" PI-STACK with cable management by Phoenix"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leqDU.jpg)

Independent reviews:
http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/PI-Stack/PI-Stack.html

Comment: Great Hi quality picture!  [e-bay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=+PI-STACK&_sacat=0)  That case is wicked!

Comment: There is now a Youtube video showing how to construct a simple cable management system for the Raspberry Pi/PI-STACK system. Here's the link:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dstji8ftZAY

Answer (score 2):

There are several cases designed for 3D printers at [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/search?q=raspberry%20pi%20case). Some of the designs are not yet ready, but you can order most of them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the canonical list of [Raspberry Pi Cases](http://elinux.org/RPi_Cases).

(I have a few Pi Sandwiches. They're basic, but fine for the money.)